# which one is right between recognize and know here?

Tags: word-usage

For a person that isn't stranger we should say I know or I recognize? Totally what's the difference betwen recognize and know? Give me some example please.

Comment: Have you checked a [dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/)? That might resolve everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize and know are both different levels of being acquainted with someone. If you were to recognize someone you would be said to vaguely recall them, but you probably wouldn't be friends with them or know them personally.

Know is different, in that it implies a deeper knowledge of the person-- really anywhere from seeing them in the news a lot to having some form of relationship with them.

[Know](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=know&oq=know&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2j0l3.1050j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8):

> "have developed a relationship with (someone) through meeting and spending time with them; be familiar or friendly with."

[Recognize](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=know&oq=know&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2j0l3.1050j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=recognize):

> "identify (someone or something) from having encountered them before; know again."

So the word you would use depends on how deep your connection with the subject is:

> "I know my best friend's wife."
>
> "I could probably recognize the wine we had back in '08."

Comment: Great! If my answer helped you, you could up-vote and accept it! :) ([Further reading](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).)